How to run a JavaFX app in Eclipse with Gradle dependencies?
If I try to run a JavaFX app with a classic classpath inside Eclipse then I get follow warning:
WARNUNG: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @7b58231a'
That I try to run it with named modules. Then I get the follow error:
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found, required by JavaFxSample
The module-info look like:
module JavaFxSample {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.web;
}

The build.gardle look:
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 17

javafx {
    version = '' + sourceCompatibility + '.+'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.web' ]
}

It look like that Gradle has detect that it is a module:

If I add the follow to the Gradle script it has no effect:
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath = true
}

I am use:

Eclipse 2024-03 (4.31)
Gradle 8.4

How can I force that that the modules from Gradle dependencies are added to the launcher modulpath inside Eclipse? Is this a JavaFX problem or an Eclipse/Gradle problem?

Seems there is a bug in Eclipse since 3 years: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576577

Don't you need the org.javamodularity.moduleplugin as well?

@jewelsea I follow already this instructions but this has all no effect. This instructions are some years old and seams not to work with the current versions.

@DaveB If I try it with org.javamodularity.moduleplugin then javafx jar files are not market as module and it does not compile in Eclipse.

@jewelsea If you does not use Eclipse and Gradle, why you think that this work with the current version? If you look into the history then you see that it is years old. And my build.gradle in my question is reduced to the part that has an effect to Eclipse. Application is needed for building the jar file an jlink for creating a launcher. Both can be used later but for the first step of writing the code and debug it in the IDE it has no effect.

Replaced comments with an answer.

@Horcrux7 I can't speak on Eclipse, but based on your build file, all you'd need to do is execute the Gradle run task and you won't get the warning. That's because org.openjfx.javafxplugin will configure that task to put JavaFX on the module-path if and as needed. Perhaps Eclipse is not executing that task when you run/debug your application from the IDE (note that in general, IDEs should be configured to delegate build tasks to the build tool when one is present).

"Perhaps Eclipse is not executing that task when you run/debug your application from the IDE (note that in general, IDEs should be configured to delegate build tasks to the build tool when one is present)." -> yes, that appeared to be the case with the Eclipse/Gradle combo I was using in my answer as well.  When run directly from the gradle task it would work, but unlike Idea, there didn't seem to be an option to debug like that.  I ended up using a JDK that included JavaFX instead.  Then the Eclipse IDE could run and debug the app directly without additional module path settings.

You need enable the module support for Gradle in Eclipse.
Window > Preferences: Gradle > Experimental features: Enable module support

These instructions are for creating a modular (in Java platform terms) project using Gradle and Eclipse.  If your project is non-modular, then likely the existing similar question will work:

How to add JavaFX runtime to Eclipse in Java 11?

I did not try the steps in that question with modern Eclipse and Java/JavaFX versions, but the accepted answer is highly upvoted, so likely helped many people at some time in the past.

Getting started instructions for developing modular JavaFX applications using Eclipse is at openjfx.io. Follow the section "JavaFX and Eclipse: Modular with Gradle".
There are also instructions for other project types, IDEs and build systems in the openjfx getting started instructions.  You could switch to one of those alternatives if you continue to have issues with your chosen combination.
Outcome for me for following openjfx.io instructions
Note: These steps detail the outcome of my following the openjfx.io instructions today.  The steps required in the future may change.

I downloaded a recent version of Eclipse (rather than the old 2020 version listed in the openjfx instructions).

I chose the most basic version of Eclipse offered, with the fewest included plugins in the distribution.
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2024-09 R version.


I also used OpenJFX 22.0.2 on OS X (x64).

When creating a new gradle project (instructions "1. Create a Gradle project"), in the dialog, I set the java path to the installed OpenJFX 22.0.2 JDK and I also manually set the Gradle version to 8.10.2 (as the default version used by the Gradle Wrapper was 8.1, which is incompatible with recent Java versions). Replace the JDK path from the dialog below with your JDK installation path.




The default gradle project created included no source or build.gradle, so I copied them per the instructions "2. Modify the build" and "3. Add the module-info class".

For instructions "4. Run the project" it was also necessary to synch the gradle build with the IDE (press the "Refresh Tasks for All Projects" button in the "Gradle Tasks" icon).  The refresh icon is the arrows pointing left and right which are the second last yellow icon in the Gradle tasks window header in the the picture below.  After that, all of the required tasks are shown in the "Gradle Tasks" window as gradle tasks.




After double clicking HelloFX > build > build and then HelloFX > application > run as per the instructions, the application ran with the following output:


How to import the Gradle build into the IDE so that it fully synchronizes
After completing the above steps, the application files can be seen in the IDE and the application can be run from the IDE via the Gradle Tasks.
But for full IDE integration (meaning having the IDE fully recognize the code and run and debug it through IDE configurations), it is necessary to Import the Gradle Project into the IDE.  To do this, see:

Build Gradle projects with Eclipse Buildship

After the import, you will see that the screen looks a bit different as there are now icons in the project tree window that show that Eclipse is recognizing source file types (compare the screenshot below with the previous screenshot from before the import).

Now, you can try running your main application class by right-clicking on it in the project tree and choosing Run As | Java Application.  However, for me, it failed (as in the asker's case), with this message:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found, required by hellofx

How to get Eclipse to recognize the JavaFX modules
To fix this, is necessary to get Eclipse to place JavaFX on the module path when you run the application.  I tried for some time to find a good way to do this by getting the gradle JavaFX config synched with the Eclipse module path, but my Eclipse/Gradle skills are limited and I was unable to achieve success with that approach.
What I did instead, was switch the JDK out from OpenJDK, to a JDK that includes JavaFX.  Azul "JDK FX" or Liberica "Full JDK" should work here for that purpose.  In my case I chose Liberica "Full JDK" 23 from Bellsoft.  I also updated the JavaFX version referenced in build.gradle so it matched at 23.
Then I closed the project, and reimported the gradle project into Eclipse, this time overriding the java home on import to the new JDK location.

After that, run worked by right-clicking the app class and choosing Run As | Java Application:

And debug also worked, by right-clicking the app class and choosing Debug As | Java Application, after right-clicking a line in the gutter to the left of the source file to set a breakpoint:

FAQ

If you does not use Eclipse and Gradle, why you think that this work with the current version?

Others who have followed the openjfx.io getting started instructions have reported them working in the past.  The instructions up until now, are not perfectly maintained, so you may encounter some issues (such as those I outlined above).  However, the instructions are reasonably well-maintained and comprehensive, so they form a good starting point.
Also, I recently tried following the instructions myself to verify them as outlined above.

If you look into the history then you see that it is years old.

As of when this answer was created, the modular JavaFX Gradle sample project for Eclipse was refreshed for modern JavaFX version support (21+) on Jan 10 2024, eight and a half months ago.  This can be seen in the project history on github.

my build.gradle in my question is reduced to the part that has an effect to Eclipse

Perhaps it was reduced too much, it doesn't include the eclipse plugin id 'eclipse'.
According to the instructions at openjfx.io: "the use of the eclipse plugin is required to include the modules to the module path."

Application is needed for building the jar file an jlink for creating a launcher.

For me, the application run target for plugin id 'application' is used to successfully run the application (not packaging) as per the openjfx instructions: "4. Run the project You can open the Gradle Task window and click on build -> build to build the project, and application -> run to run the project."

I does not want to run the application via a Gradle task. This is working without any problems (without my code). In this case there is no interoperation with Eclipse. I want DEBUG it inside Eclipse to find problems in my code.

I updated this answer with an additional section importing the gradle project to completely synch it with the IDE and updating the JDK used to one that includes JavaFX, so that debug and other IDE features will work as expected with the project.

What if I have third-party modules as dependencies and want them on the module path?

Adding additional third-party modules as dependencies is beyond the scope of the question.  Also, I didn't try it.
Hopefully, if you add the modules as dependencies in Gradle and resync the Gradle project with Eclipse, then Eclipse will automatically update the existing run and debug configurations to add the additional dependencies to the module path (rather than the classpath).  Otherwise, you will need to edit the run and debug configuration and do that manually.

I does not want to run the application via a Gradle task. This is working without any problems (without my code). In this case there is no interoperation with Eclipse. I want DEBUG it inside Eclipse to find problems in my code. Building and running is not the problem. I have try a 100% copy of the sample. It does not run the debug.
I have also try a very simple module sample without javaFX, it is also not working with debugging.

@Horcrux7 Yes indeed, a development environment without a debugger is not acceptable.  I updated the answer to demonstrate how to get the IDE integration and debugger working with a modular JavaFX project in Eclipse.

@Horcrux7 One thing you might be able to try is to pass --debug-jvm when executing the Gradle run task. Then run some action in Eclipse to attach a debugger to the "remote" application (note the app will, by default, suspend waiting for a debugger to attach). Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Eclipse, so I can't give exact steps to do that. That said, both IntelliJ and VS Code provide a way to directly debug a Gradle task at the push of a button. I would assume Eclipse offers something similar?
